# Bash Script to poll SFTP directory

Tags: linux, bash, sftp

I have 2 separate, and very simple bash scripts running on an ubuntu server, responsible for uploading & downloading files to an external vendor directory via SFTP. The scripts look as follows

**Upload**

```
export SSHPASS="$LICENCEPASS"
sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -oPort="$SFTP_PORT" 
"$LICENCENUM"@"$SFTP_HOST" << !
put $REQFILE
bye
!
```

**Download**

```
export SSHPASS="$LICENCEPASS"
sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -oPort="$SFTP_PORT" 
"$LICENCENUM"@"$SFTP_HOST" << !
get $OUTFILE
rm $OUTFILE
bye
!
```

When the request file gets pushed up to the vendor it might take up to a minute for a corresponding response file to be generated (it could also happen in a second depending on the amount of data that is requested). My question is, is it possible to poll this directory until the response file is generated and then run the download. Currently, I'm running the first script, waiting a minute and then running the second script which isn't ideal. Ideally, i would like the above two code snippets to belong to the same script with a section in between the two that polls the directory until the response file is ready to be downloaded. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless there is a logicscriptable `sftp` client  (if/then/else)  out there (I don't think so, did you look at `lftp`?) what you're doing is a reasonable solution Any solution I can think of will require more than one process, so `ssh`ing to the remote to poll will only save you those X seconds between min-write-time and max-write-time. Are you sure your boss thinks this is a good use of your time? (Or research `inotify/inotifywait`, but that won't work on a remote file-system without an nfs mount.) Good luck.

Comment: I had a sneaky suspicion this would be the case. I hadn't looked at lftp, but will do so briefly now on the off chance it proves fruitful. It isn't the end of the world if there's no solution to this problem, but I guess it would have been nice to execute just the one script instead of two. Many thanks for your response @shellter

Comment: Just an idea, ... Maybe this can all be run from using `expect` or `perl` or `python', but is it really worth the time? Good luck.

Comment: The thoughts of using Python had crossed my mind, and I'm sure it's achievable, but I think your last sentence sums up my thought's exactly... It's not really worth my time. I really just wanted to know if it were possible to amend the above implementation. Thanks for your advice nevertheless. If you want to change your initial comment to an answer, I'm happy to accept it!